# Prevent roles which can patch a resource to modify specific fields of a document in a rest api with express

Tags: javascript, rest, api, express, roles

Im actually creating a rest api with express.

My users have a field 'permissionLevel' (Integer) which grants them access to certain resources and verbs.

I'm actually looking for an elegant way to allow only specific fields on the PATCH of a resource depending on the permissionLevel of a user.

Let's say a user with permissionLevel 3 can edit the name field of other users while another with permissionLevel 2 can't. But they both have access to the verb PATCH of the user resource.

And next step would be : A user with permissionLevel 3 can't update another with a higher permissionLevel.

I could do it simply by adding code in my controllers, but i'd like to not do it if possible, and handling it with a middleware or something. I'd like to make it as generic as possible. And staying in accordance with rest conventions.

I searched a lot on the internet, but I couldn't find anything that answered my questions, so if you have any resources to advise me, I'll take it.

Thank's in advance !